# Formatting for problem sets?

Tags: proof-writing

What is considered a good format for writing problem sets in mathematics? Are there any good examples of problem sets that are well-written and formatted that you can show me?

Answer (score 1):

I like to write my proofs in LaTeX. I have gotten some nice templates offline for this and modified them to my preference. I have also created a commands file so I am not constantly writing out long commands (i.e. \mathbb{R} vs. \bb{R}). I can send you the .tex files for these if you are interested.

I also like to include any definitions or theorem I will be using (in boxes after the question and before the solution). That way, if I look back at the problems and I don't remember what some definition is or what theorem makes a certain fact true in the proof, I have it right there and I don't have to hunt for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few common styles.  Personally, I like ink on printer paper, formatted either in two columns or one, depending on how wide the wide formulas get.  I cross out "mistakes" instead of erasing.

Some people like using graph (grid) paper.  Most people probably use pencils, but I find the ease of using a pen worthwhile.

The basic format for a problem is the following:

1. The problem number
2. A statement of the problem.  You should summarize it, but only once you've had enough practice that you won't make any mistakes.
3. (optional) A long dash or turnstile symbol (in this context, it would be a long dash with a pip on the bottom, like $\vdash$ turned $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians.
4. The solution/proof
5. If they ask for a numerical or formulaic answer, put it in a box.